# Probability of a rectangle containing a shaded portion?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

The question is exactly as follows:

[image: Picture from the test]

I assume that you find the total possible rectangles and then the amount containing the shaded portion and divide, but how do I do that?

Comment: Someone writing some test in 2003 forgot to provide the distribution for this random rectangle?

Comment: Your question title and question-image do not match. One asks the probability that the rectangle does not include a shaded square and one asks the probability that it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the total possible rectangles?

So you have 2003 length and 2 height. A rectangle would consists of 2 vertical and 2 horizontal lines.

1. Vertical lines = 2004
2. Horizontal lines = 3

Total number of rectangles = ways to choose 2 vertical lines $\times$ ways to choose two horizontal lines. 
$$Total = \binom{2004}{2}\times\binom{3}{2}$$

How how many ways are there to choose rectangles that don't include the middle column?

$$NotShaded = 2\times\binom{1002}{2}\times\binom{3}{2}$$

So probability $P$ that the rectangle contains a shaded portion is $1-P'$ where $P'$ is the probability that it doesn't contain shaded portion. 
$$P'=\frac{6\times \binom{1002}{2}}{3\times\binom{2004}{2}}=\frac{1001}{2003}\\P=1-P'=\frac{1002}{2003}$$

Comment: So there are 3 possible ways for the horizontal aspect of the rectangle but how would you find the vertical options, because there are a lot more than just 2004?

Comment: Using combinations. Look at the complete solution. This technique is very useful in probability you can find the probability of the complement set and subtract from 1 to get the probability of the event.

Comment: Thank You, This is a really simple way to look at the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If a sub-rectangle of the given rectangle avoids a shaded square, it must reside fully in either the left half or the right half.

Let $f(i,j)$ be the number of sub-rectangles of an $i\,{\times}\,j$ rectangle.

Then the probability that a randomly chosen sub-rectangle of the given rectangle avoids a shaded square is
$$\frac{2f(2,1001)}{f(2,2003)}$$
To finish the problem, note that
$$f(i,j) = \left(\binom{i}{2} + i\right)\left(\binom{j}{2} + j\right)$$
Explanation:

Choose the starting and ending rows:

- ${\large{\binom{i}{2}}}$ choices if the starting and ending rows are not the same.$\\[4pt]$

  $i$ choices if the starting and ending rows are the same.$\\[4pt]$

Choose the starting and ending columns:

- ${\large{\binom{j}{2}}}$ choices if the starting and ending columns are not the same.$\\[4pt]$

  $j$ choices if the starting and ending columns are the same.$\\[4pt]$

Comment: This another way of looking at the same problem, but in my opinion the other one is faster so I accepted it. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ be the number of rectangles contained in the bottom row, and let $m$ be the number of rectangles in the bottom row which contain a shaded square. There are $n$ rectangles contained in the top row and $n$ rectangles spanning both rows, so there are $3n$ rectangles in the figure. Similarly, $3m$ rectangles contain a shaded square. The probability that a rectangle chosen at random includes a shaded square is $3m/3n=m/n$.

A rectangle contained in the bottom row is determined by choosing any two of the 2004 vertical segments as sides of the rectangle. Therefore, $n=\binom{2004}{2}=\frac{2004\cdot 2003}{2}=1002\cdot2003$. A rectangle in the bottom row which contains a shaded square is determined by choosing one side from among the 1002 vertical segments to the left of the shaded square and one side from among the 1002 vertical segments to the right of the shaded square. Therefore, $m=1002^2$. The probability that a rectangle chosen at random from the figure does not include a shaded square is $1-\dfrac{m}{n}=1-\dfrac{1002^2}{1002\cdot 2003}=1-\dfrac{1002}{2003}=\boxed{\dfrac{1001}{2003}}$.